# How can I make a network-manager profile without tying it to a MAC address?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, networkmanager

I want to make an SD card image (Raspberry Pi) that is set up to connect to a certain WiFi network using network-manager (such that it automatically reconnects). However, each different device has a different MAC address. This causes the profile I made with `nmcli` to not be used.

How can I make a network-manager profile that works with any MAC address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# nmcli connection edit id XXXX
nmcli> describe 802-11-wireless.mac-address
=== [mac-address] ===
[NM property description]
If specified, this connection will only apply to the Wi-Fi device whose permanent MAC address matches. This property does not change the MAC address of the device (i.e. MAC spoofing).
```

This can also be found in [`nm-settings(5)`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/network-manager/nm-settings.5.en.html).

So, just don't specify it by removing it. Which can be scripted simply with:

```
# nmcli connection modify id XXXX 802-11-wireless.mac-address ''
```

as explained in [`nmcli(1)`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/network-manager/nmcli.1.en.html#CONNECTION_MANAGEMENT_COMMANDS):

> modify [--temporary] [id | uuid | path] ID { option value |
>   [+|-]setting. property  value}...
>
> Add, modify or remove properties in the connection profile.
>
> To set the property just specify the property name followed by the value.
>   **An empty value ("") removes the property value**.

Be sure you still have other properties (eg `connection.interface-name`) to identify unambiguously the correct device. And be careful if reconfiguring the settings with a graphical tool, it might reapply some unwanted default values.